Shanghai Passenger Ferry Terminal
Shinganjin are currently not accepting passengers on their ferries from Osaka to Shanghai, citing construction delays at the Shanghai Passenger Ferry Terminal.
Is there any public information about that construction that would allow educated guesses when that ferry service will restart?
